# Handling Index Minimum Formula with Duplicated

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, formula, minimum

I tried searching the web for a solution but couldn't really find anything helpful. I am not a pro with google sheets formulas and I am running into an issue with the index/minimum function.

[Please view the screenshot of my google Sheet here][1]

So basically what I am trying to do in cell B14 is to show me the alias/name with the least amount open revenue (column B). There are duplicates in that column (more than one alias has $0.00), but the formula will only show me the first alias in the name with that value and ignoring all other duplicates...Is there a way to solve this and maybe show all alias/names in one cell that have that minimum value?

Comment: comma separated perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=JOIN(", "; FILTER(A3:A8; B3:B8=MIN(B3:B8)))
```